# Big Commerce API - Get order by date with time zone correction

Tags: bigcommerce

I am trying to create a simple widget to display my stores sales totals for the current day. However, when i retrieve orders by date using "min_date_created" the order dates being returned are the incorrect timezone (+0000).

```
https://mystore.com/api/v2/orders?min_date_created=2015-01-19

<order>
<id>012345</id>
<customer_id>123</customer_id>
<date_created>Mon, 19 Jan 2015 00:06:48 +0000</date_created>
<date_modified>Mon, 19 Jan 2015 01:56:47 +0000</date_modified>
....
</order>
```

Is there a way to retrieve orders by date with the correct timezone of my store (-5:00 Eastern Time)?

Thanks

Comment: I figured it out. You have to pass the date using date-time defined by RFC 2822 (Tue, 20 Jan 2015 00:00:00 -0500). You also have to encode the date-time. ex. https://mystore.com/api/v2/orders?min_date_created=Tue%2C%2020%20Jan%202015%2000%3A00%3A00%20-0500